# Canvas JS chart not displaying when pulling from MySQL

Tags: jsp, canvasjs

Can anyone see a reason why the below will not display the doughnut chart as it should? Depending on where I close the while it will display the chart but only with the final entry from the database while it prints the other two entries which should be pulled in text as `{ label: "Ireland",  y: 2 }`. I think if have closed the while  in the right place now but nothing displays. ( i know i should be using prepared statements - apologies for inexperience)

```
 <%

                            Statement stat = null;
                            ResultSet res = null;
                            stat = conn.createStatement();
                            String data = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS count_user, user_country FROM user GROUP BY user_country;";

                            res = stat.executeQuery(data);

                            while(res.next()){
                        %>


                        <tr>
                            <td><%= res.getInt("count_user")%></td>
                            <td><%= res.getString("user_country")%></td>
                           </tr>
                        <%
                            }
                         %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "Alumni by country"              
                        },

        data: 
                      [

                        {
                            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
                                type: "doughnut",

                                dataPoints:             

                                <%  res = stat.executeQuery(data);

                                 while(res.next()){
                                %> 

                                [  

                { label: "<%= res.getString("user_country")%>",  y: <%= res.getString("count_user")%> }

                                ]

                                                <%}%>
                        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
};
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related to `chart.js`, otherwise please remove this tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a missing comma after every {label ... } block (except the last of course)

Comment: Thank you @areus, are you suggesting  ` { label: "<%= res.getString("user_country")%>",  y: <%= res.getString("count_user")%> },` in the loop so? How would I prevent one being there for the last one in this case?

Comment: You could use `<% if (!rs.isLast() { %> , <% } %>`. But I think it would be more apropiate to handle the first case, before the loop, and on the loop print the comma at the begining

Comment: If this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.